# value of type 'string' has no member 'text'

Tags: swift

A part of my app is to get a number from `fextfiled` and Double in 10. I get this error message:

The alert massage is about the 2 sentence at the code down here.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Picker1: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var num: UITextField!

    var array1 = ["km","m","dm","mm"]
    var PlaceAnswer = 0
    var answer = Float()
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()   
    }
     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

       return array1[row]

    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{

        return array1.count
    }

     func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }
    @IBAction func Submit(sender: AnyObject) {

        if(PlaceAnswer==0){
answer = num.text
            label.text = ("\(answer)")

        }
```

Comment: please add your error message

Comment: Please include your error message

Answer (score 0):

NSNumberFormatter can translate String to NSNumber:

```
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
let number = numberFormatter.numberFromString(num.text)!
answer = number.floatValue
```

Comment: if i want to add 2 to answer how i do this?

Comment: @EyalZaidman I'm not sure if I understand your request. Like this? "answer += 2"

Comment: i want that the number that get on the textfield double in 2 for example and the answer will pop.

 @IBAction func Submit(sender: AnyObject) {
       
        if(PlaceAnswer==0){
            let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
            numberFormatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
            let number = numberFormatter.numberFromString(num.text!)
            answer += 2
            answer = number!.floatValue
           
            label.text =  ("\(answer)")
        }